# Array including multiple view types in Swift/SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to create a view where people can choose their preferred background image, these include a rectangle with a foreground colour or an image. So far I've got this to work by creating this

**Struct:**

```
struct BackgroundImage : Identifiable{
var background : AnyView
let id = UUID()
}
```

I am adding them to an array like so

**ViewModel:**

```
class VM : ObservableObject{
    @Published var imageViews : Array<BackgroundImage> = Array<BackgroundImage>()
        
    init(){
        imageViews.append(BackgroundImage(background: AnyView(Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.green))))
        imageViews.append(BackgroundImage(background: AnyView(Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.yellow))))
        imageViews.append(BackgroundImage(background: AnyView(Image("Testimage"))))
    }
```

which allows me to loop through an array of BackgroundImages like so

**View:**

```
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]) {
    ForEach(VM.imageViews, id: \.self.id) { view in
        ZStack{
            view.background
            //.resizable()
            //.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(width: g.size.width/2.25, height: g.size.height/8)                                                                                  
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
        }
    }
}
```

However I am unable to add

```
 .resizable()
 .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
```

for the images as AnyView doesn't allow this.

Is there a better way of achieving this? Should I just have two separate arrays for Shapes/Images instead? Or is there an alternate View struct that would be better suited this?

Thanks!

Comment: A viewmodel storing actual views is a very bad design. Your business logic and UI should be separated in a way that only the view can access your business logic (view models), but the view models have no knowledge of or access to the UI.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Thanks for the insight, how would you suggest reorganising this logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DávidPásztor mentioned in the comments, it is a bad design to store Views in your ViewModel.

Really you just need to store a color and an image name.  Let the view building code construct the actual views.

Here is a possible implementation.

```
struct BackgroundItem: Identifiable {
    private let uicolor: UIColor?
    private let imageName: String?
    let id = UUID()
    
    var isImage: Bool { imageName != nil }
    var color: UIColor { uicolor ?? .white }
    var name: String { imageName ?? "" }
    
    init(name: String? = nil, color: UIColor? = nil) {
        imageName = name
        uicolor = color
    }
}

class VM : ObservableObject{
    @Published var imageItems: [BackgroundItem] = []
        
    init() {
        imageItems = [.init(color: .green),
                      .init(color: .blue),
                      .init(name: "TestImage")]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = VM()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { g in
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]) {
                ForEach(vm.imageItems) { item in
                    ZStack{
                        if item.isImage {
                            Image(item.name)
                                .resizable()
                                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        } else {
                            Color(item.color)
                        }
                    }
                    .frame(width: g.size.width/2.25, height: g.size.height/8)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I thought of using an `enum` to store the distinction between imageName and color, but it was simplest to just use optionals and store the one I needed.  With the interface that is being exposed to the view building code, you could easily change the implementation to however you'd like to store the information.